# Get the input argument from xaml and use it with dynamic activities in WF 4 via MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I am trying to make a Native Activity that I can reuse in xaml that basically replicates the functionality of PolicyActivity from WF3.x, which is a Rules Engine with a GUI to edit rules.

My problem is that when I call `WorkflowInvoker.Invoke`, it says that Model, which is the `InArgument` is `Null`, which I know it's not because this code works as a function that returns an Activity as it does from Frode Nilsen's blog:
[Using WF 4 as a Rules Engine](http://www.nilzorblog.com/2011/11/using-wf4-as-rule-engine.html) My question is, am I getting the `InArgument` correctly from the Xaml activity?

```
 public sealed class RuleSequenceAcitvity : NativeActivity<Sequence>
{
    private Sequence _sequence;
    InArgument<HomeIndexViewModel> Model { get; set; } //Same name as inArgument in xaml

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        populateSequence();
        var input = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        //The following line is giving me the Null Argument Exception
        var model = context.GetValue<HomeIndexViewModel>(this.Model);
        input.Add("Model", model);
        WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(_sequence, input);

    }

    private void populateSequence()
    {
        //get the list of rules from repository
        var rules = ObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<IRuleRepository>().Rules.ToList();

        //Declare a dynamic property as the view model
        var inProperty = new DynamicActivityProperty
        {
            Name = "Model",
            Type = typeof(InArgument<HomeIndexViewModel>),
            Value = Model
        };
        var activity = new DynamicActivity() { Properties = { inProperty } };

        //Import references
        Common.AddVbSetting(activity);

        _sequence = new Sequence();
        activity.Implementation = () => _sequence;

        //Sort Descending - those added first are lowest priority
        var sortedRules = rules.OrderBy(x => x.Priority).ToList();

        foreach (var inRule in rules)
        {
            var outRule = RuleConverter.ToIfActivity(inRule);
            _sequence.Activities.Add(outRule);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Just as an update, I just checked the InArgument, Model, in the XAML and it is populated as it should be. This way to get the InArgument from the context is the same as is described in the stock code on every new CodeActivity but it doesn't work in my case for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.

First of all, you've to declare your `InArgument<HomeIndexViewModel>` as public. Otherwise whichever calls the activity won't be able to bind its inputs to it.

Second, it isn't your `_sequence` that receives input arguments. It's the dynamic activity which you've to invoke and pass the argument, not the sequence.

Finally, you're correctly creating the `DynamicActivityProperty` but in this case you don't need to set it's Value. When you call `Workflow.Invoker()` with an input called `"Model"` that same input will be binded to the dynamic property.

I've just edited your code, without running it. Hope it helps! :)

```
public sealed class RuleSequenceAcitvity : NativeActivity<Sequence>
{
    private DynamicActivity _dynamicActivity;
    public InArgument<HomeIndexViewModel> Model { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        populateDynamicActivity();

        var input = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        // It was throwing a null reference because Model
        // was private, so the input that the activity was receiving 
        // was never binded to it.

        var model = context.GetValue<HomeIndexViewModel>(this.Model);
        input.Add("Model", model);

        // It's the dynamic activity that contains input arguments.
        // Not the sequence. 

        WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(_dynamicActivity, input);
    }

    private void populateDynamicActivity()
    {
        //get the list of rules from repository
        var rules = 
            ObjectFactory
            .Container
            .GetInstance<IRuleRepository>()
            .Rules
            .ToList();

        //Declare a dynamic property as the view model
        var inProperty = new DynamicActivityProperty
        {
            Name = "Model",
            Type = typeof(InArgument<HomeIndexViewModel>)
        };

        _dynamicActivity = new DynamicActivity() 
        { 
            Properties = { inProperty } 
        };

        //Import references
        Common.AddVbSetting(activity);

        var sequence = new Sequence();
        activity.Implementation = () => sequence

        //Sort Descending - those added first are lowest priority
        var sortedRules = rules.OrderBy(x => x.Priority).ToList();

        foreach (var inRule in rules)
        {
            var outRule = RuleConverter.ToIfActivity(inRule);
            sequence.Activities.Add(outRule);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and suggestions. I definitely did need to change those things you pointed out and I appreciate you letting me know. However, even after making InArgument<> public, the value of model from 'var model = context.GetValue<HomeIndexViewModel>(this.Model);' is still null. Any Suggestions as to why it is not getting the value from the xaml?

Comment: Almost certaintly because your XAML isn't passing the `Model` argument to `RuleSequenceAcitvity` activity but I can only say something after seing the XAML itself although I'm not that confortable editing XAML by hand. Why aren't you using workflow designer?

Comment: I actually am using the designer. I am still very new to WF so I guess I use "xaml" and "designer" interchangeably. In my designer, I have an InArgument called Model which is of the correct type. So are you sure that the code to get the argument from the Designer is correct though?

Comment: I just realized I have to specify the Model argument in the properties panel of my sub activity and not just in the Activity arguments panel. Thanks for all your help!